# Function template that is a member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyStruct
{
    template <typename FunType>
    void fun(size_t idx)
    {
        if (idx == 0)
            return;

        MyStruct<FunType> obj;
        obj.fun<FunType>(idx - 1);
    }
};
```

Compiling this piece of code produces the following error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
  obj.fun<FunType>(idx - 1);
                 ^
```

Strangely, changing the line `MyStruct<FunType> obj;` to e.g. `MyStruct<int> obj;` (or any other type except FunType) seems to solve the problem. Can somebody explain to me what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need `obj.template fun<FunType>(idx - 1);` to tell the compiler you are calling a template function since `obj` is a dependent name.

Comment: Ah, that page is indeed very helpful, thanks!